# Complex WHERE clause on an array in Azure DocumentDb

Tags: linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two documents which looks like this.

```
{      
  "CustomFields": [
    {
      "CustomFieldId": "FirstName",
      "StringValue": "John",          
    },
    {
      "CustomFieldId": "LastName",
      "StringValue": "Johnson",          
    }
  ],      
  "id": "f600bd8b-bca8-41a5-9f1c-0038e9cc7b35",      
},
{
  "CustomFields": [
    {
      "CustomFieldId": "FirstName",
      "StringValue": "John",          
    },
    {
      "CustomFieldId": "LastName",
      "StringValue": "Williams",          
    }
  ],      
  "id": "f600bd8b-bca8-41a5-9f1c-0038e9cc7b35",      
}
```

I have tried this:

```
items = items.Where(x => x.CustomFields.All(
                cf =>
                    cf.CustomFieldId == "01d1beab-8651-41df-ad93-ecc6195e912f" && cf.StringValue == "Pending"));
```

I'd like to build a query (either in SQL or LINQ - as long as its executable by documentdb) that will retrieve all the documents

```
where (CustomFieldId == "FirstName" and StringValue == "John") 
  AND (CustomFieldId == "LastName" and StringValue == "Williams")
```

Please **do not** suggest using `ARRAY_CONTAINS` as I need to leverage the indexes as the collection contains over 500,000 docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a SQL query that looks like this -

```
SELECT d 
FROM docs d 
JOIN f1 IN d.CustomFields 
JOIN f2 IN d.CustomFields 
WHERE (f1.CustomFieldId = "FirstName" and f1.StringValue == "John") 
AND (f2.CustomFieldId == "LastName" and f2.StringValue == "Williams")
```

Comment: This works great... only negative part is as many joins as different conditions... performance might be an issue here

Comment: @ryan-crawcour-msft I will have up to 10 different conditions (items in the array) that Ill be comparing against.  This also means 10 possible joins, should there be a performance hit against my collection with over 500,000 docs?

Comment: Please note that DocumentDb limits the number of joins to two, so as much as this was the correct answer it didn't meet my ultimate needs. On a positive note, the performance of the query was excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `All`, that only returns a boolean `true` if **every single** element satisfies your condition.

```
items = items.Where(x => 
            x.CustomFields.Where(cf => cf.CustomFieldId == "FirstName" && cf.StringValue == "John").Count() > 0
            && x.CustomFields.Where(cf.CustomFieldId == "LastName" && cf.StringValue == "Williams").Count() > 0);
```

Comment: I don't want to select the custom fields though, I need parent.... Also not or (||) it has to meet both conditions

Comment: **if every single element satisfies your condition.** I actually wanted this.... the problem is that its not supported

Comment: The `||` in the `Where` clause actually *is* an AND operator in this case, because it will give you both things you ask it for. If you were to put `&&` as you did, you will never get any results, because `cf.CustomFieldId` can never be equal to `"FirstName"` and `"LastName"` at the same time.

Comment: **if every single element satisfies your condition.** So you really wanted this? To return a boolean, not a list of the corresponding objects?

Comment: OHH i re read your question and i see what you want now... answer edited.

Comment: it would have returned all parent items with the TRUE condition....

**items.Where(x => x.CustomFields.All())**

Comment: thanks Andrew, this would have worked except Any() is not supported by documentdb

Comment: Count is also not supported by documentdb :(